# Installing Python Module in pycharm From GitHub

Tags: python, module, pycharm

I have downloaded the py-earth module from GitHub and followed the provided installation procedures as well as done "pip install". Things seem to be installing in the terminal, but I cant find the module when I am in pycharm. I have restarted pycharm, reinstalled, and no matter what I can't find a way to install the module. Please help

Answer (score 3):

Have you gone into your settings and set your project interpreter in `settings > Project: {project-name}> Project Interpreter` to your version of python that has the module you installed?

Answer (score 0):

From pycharm,

goto `settings` -> `project Interpreter`

Click on `+` button on top right corner and you will get pop-up window of Available packages. Then search for `earth` python package.

Then click on Install package to install the `earth` package.